# How to show/hide <div> when <mat-checkbox> is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'd like to show/hide a `<div>` when a `<mat-checkbox>` is checked/unchecked.

My checkbox is the following code:

```
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="rushDelivery">
             Rush Delivery
          </mat-checkbox>
```

And the `<div>` I want to show/hide will be below the checkbox, further down on the page.

I have used `[(ngModel)]` and `*ngIf` in the past, however from my understanding, the latest version of Angular does not support `[(ngModel)]` and `*ngIf` if `formControlName` is also used in the same element.

I cannot remove the `formControlName` since I use it to get the value of the checkbox upon the submission of the form. I also don't want to touch that portion of the code in case I break the form.

What would be the easiest alternative solution to show/hide the `<div>` when the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Angular, but I would go about this by adding an on change listener to the checkbox using javascript, then simply applying styling (display: none) to the div that you're trying to hide if the box is checked

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://codippa.com/how-to-toggle-element-display-in-angular/

Comment: @edtung [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64584744/13864358)

Comment: @Ibz, well, in Angular the things is made it in another way: relation variables and .html

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML-

```
<mat-checkbox (click)='toggle()'>
   Rush Delivery
</mat-checkbox>
<div [hidden]='isHidden'>
   <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

In your TS, initially define isHidden variable to false-

```
 isHidden=false;
```

In your function-

```
toggle(){
    this.isHidden=!this.isHidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution. It has helped me.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the value of a FormControl using get, so, if your formGroup is called, e.g. form, you only need

```html
    <div *ngIf="form.get('rushDelivery').value">
      ..If you can see this is because...
      ..the checkbox is checked..
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `[(ngModel)]` won't work with `formControlName`, you can still show/hide the `div` in serval ways.

option 1: add `*ngIf="form.rushDelivery"` onto the `div` that you want to show/hide

option 2: add `(change)="checked = change.checked"` callback to `mat-checkbox` and add `*ngIf="checked"` onto the `div`

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways for achieving the solution, to show/hide the div!

.html

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="rushDelivery" (click)='showOrHide()'>
   Rush Delivery
</mat-checkbox>
<div [class.hide]='isVisible'>
   Some info ...
</div>
```

.ts

```
isVisible = true;
showOrHide(){
   this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
}
```

.css

```
.hide{
    display: none;
 }
```

Comment: your aproach is not "the easiest" aproach. you can simply use a *ngIf, and no code in .ts